# Show brightness level in status bar

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dwm

I have the following config (using intel graphics before):

```
Thinkpad T495 (AMD Vega Graphics)
Arch Linux with dwm Window Manager
```

I have the status bar filled with xsetroot using a shell script (https://dwm.suckless.org/status_monitor/).
Since xbacklight is not supported on AMD, I am running brightnessctl to change backlight.

```
brightnessctl
Device 'amdgpu_bl0' of class 'backlight':
        Current brightness: 128 (50%)
        Max brightness: 255
cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
128
```

How do I get my script to display backlight level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the part you have script. In the suckless example it's only the result of `date` but ut can be anything you like.

```
while true; do
    brightness = $(cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness)
    xsetroot -name "$(date) Level: $brightness"
    sleep 2
done
```

`dwm` is very simple, it'll display anything you put in the name field of the root window (background). 
In the example above it's the date and contents if a file. You can extend this script to output all the things you want. However it's often safer to use a ready-made script with structure and reliability.

`slstatus` is a program that compiles a string of useful information and sets it for you. Other status bar programs like `i3blocks`, `conky` and `lemonbar` will just compile a string for you. 
None these types of status bars are rescource demanding even compared to minimal variants like `tint2`, `stalonetray` and `xfce4-panel`.

To use `slstatus` for backlight display you could utilize the `run_command` (with `cat /sys/clas...` ) module or write your own based off one of the existing modules.

Comment: So "slstatus" mentioned here https://dwm.suckless.org/status_monitor/  could be an alternative then. Does it have less need for resources or what is better about using a bar?

Comment: @skeebolt A poorly written script can impact performance but nothing here is resource intensive. I updated my answer with some clarifications. Please upvote or mark it as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: accepted as upvoting public is not allowed for me

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do
    xsetroot -name ":$(expr $(expr $(cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness) / 1210) + 1)%"
    sleep 1
done
```

My status bar:

https://github.com/felipefacundes/dotfiles/blob/master/config/dwm/barcomplete.sh

I put everything I need, in a single script and for me it's perfect like that.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipefacundes/dotfiles/master/config/ScreenShots/Captura%20de%20tela%20de%2024-02-2020%2016%3A11%3A20.png